# Como imprimir um documento qualquer pelo cmd?

Tags: cmd, impressora

Há alguma forma de imprimir um documento(de formato .docx ou .pdf de preferência) usando uma linha de comando do cmd do Windows?
Eu tentei usar o print mas ele resulta num erro que diz "Não é possível inicializar o dispositivo USB002(impressora)"

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o comando `PRINT` especificando para qual impressora quer enviar o arquivo.

```
PRINT filename.txt /D:<printer_name>
```

Ou você pode utilizar o Adobe para fazer isso:

```
AcroRd32.exe /t <file.pdf> <printer_name> <printer_driver> <printer_port>
```

Ficando assim:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "D:\File.pdf" "Brother MFC-7820N USB Printer" "Brother MFC-7820N USB Printer" "IP_192.168.10.110"
```

Detalhes: [detalhes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137384/printing-pdf-file-directly-from-dos-command-line)

Comment: O Segundo comando imprimiu certinho!! Porém o primeiro resulta em: `Não é possível inicializar o dispositivo HP DeskJet 2130 series`. A impressora esta ligada e funcionando normalmente

Comment: Eu removi o "HP" do nome e o comando resulta em: `D:\test.docx está sendo impresso` mas nada acontece!